# Flowbite - Tailwind modal doesn't work when dynamically added

Tags: javascript, laravel, tailwind-css, dynamically-generated, flowbite

I have a Laravel project that uses API calls. When the row is generated it has a edit button that has a modal popup. The modal used to work when it was static, but now when it's dynamically added i get the following error:

**Modal with id editUserModal has not been initialized. Please
initialize it using the data-modal-target attribute.**

userTable ID:

```
<tbody id = "userTable">
    //here is where i want it to be generated
    //if i add a static row here the modal does work and i get no error
</tbody>
```

Here is the JavaScript function( i use axios ):

```
const drawUsers = () => {

    let userTable = document.getElementById("userTable");

    axios.get(API.url + API.routes.getUsers)
    .then(response =>{
        if(response.data.status){
            response.data.data.forEach(user => {
                var row = `<tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                                <th scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    ${user.username}
                                </th>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    ${user.email}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    ${user.is_active}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <button id = "editUserModal" data-modal-target="editUserModal" data-modal-toggle="editUserModal" class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-green-800">
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`;
                    userTable.innerHTML += row;
            });
        }
    })

}
```

I get generated everything correctly except the modal, what am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to dynamically generate HTML code with JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using flowbite for the modal ?

Comment: Yes i am using flowbite

Comment: 1) I would add that to the question title.
2) It may be the case that the tailwind compiler removes the required code from your page, as it is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Because it tries to get the modal ID before your data is received.

After your data is complete, you need to start the modal instance.

```js
axios.get(API.url + API.routes.getUsers)
    .then(response =>{
        if(response.data.status){
            response.data.data.forEach(user => {
                var row = `<tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                                <th scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    ${user.username}
                                </th>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    ${user.email}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    ${user.is_active}
                                </td>
                                <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                    <button id = "editUserModal" data-modal-target="editUserModal" data-modal-toggle="editUserModal" class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-green-600 dark:hover:bg-green-700 dark:focus:ring-green-800">
                                        Edit
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="button" class="focus:outline-none text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900">
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>`;
                    userTable.innerHTML += row;
            });
        }
    })
    .finally(() => {
      //You need to start modal instance here!
    })
```

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with an actual code example where it says `//You need to start modal instance here!` For instance, it it `initModals()`? Or `initFlowBite()`. Assuming it's `initModals`, is there a way to restrict the scope of the method call to only the recently added modal markup?